# Validation Exception Silverlight Validation

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am having issues validating a Textbox in a DataTemplate column of a grid. The property that the textbox is bound to is a "double" value. Here is my xaml code for the TextBox

```
 <TextBox  Text="{Binding SubTotalRawHours, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  
                                                 MinHeight="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" BindingValidationError="ValidateTime" />
```

and here is the property

```
  private double _SubTotalRawHours;
        public double SubTotalRawHours
        {
            get { return _SubTotalRawHours; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Value not allowed");
                }
                _SubTotalRawHours = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SubTotalRawHours");
            }
        }
```

Now the strange issue is that if I enter alphabets, the code is displaying a tooltip with error message "Input not in correct format", which is correct. But if I enter a negative value I get an exception "Exception was not handled by the code".
which is happening here

```
  if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Value not allowed");
                }
```

I have tried everything, i have even tried to put the textbox outside the grid but its not working.

Would really appreciate some inputs here.

**Edit 1**

OK, Now I have made some changes to the code and I have a workaround, instead of `"ValidatesOnExceptions=True"`, I have `"ValidatesOnDataErrors=True"` and my Model class now also inherits from `IDataErrorInfo` and I have implemented the IDataErrorInfo memeber in my class

```
  private string _dataError = string.Empty;
        const string _ErrorsText = "Errors";
        string IDataErrorInfo.Error
        {
            get { return _dataError; }
        }
        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                _dataError = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "OldHours":
                        if (OldHours < 0 || OldHours > 100)
                        {
                            return "Please enter a value between 0 - 100.";
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is working(Apart from the tooltip showing at wrong place but that's fine). I still cannot understand why my code didn't catch any exceptions. IS there something I had to add to my model class?

Comment: The Inner Exception is coming up as null.

Comment: i think that it is hard to say exact problem. coul you provide us with more details. Because from here there isnot any error.

Comment: Have a look at this article I have tried to follow it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86955/Silverlight-4-Data-Validation-Tip-of-the-Day-Part Besides that I am not sure what other information I can provide?

Comment: İ mean if i would copy your codes and test it in simple silverlight project, it would work like a charm. Have you test it? İf yes, then what other codes you have written in Current project.

Comment: Himm.. İ want to help you, but how we can if we dont know what you are doing else in project. :(

Comment: In your XAML `binding`, try adding `FallbackValue = 0` and see if the unhandled exception error is still thrown. `"..., NotifyOnValidationError=True, FallbackValue = 0}"`

Comment: nah it doesn't work and even if it did it would have set the property value to 0 and ignored the exception. But i wanted to rather display a message to the user. The solution to which has been provided by Alyce below. Thank you anyways for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Visual Studio is set to break on user-unhandled exceptions, it will break before the validation frameworks handles the exception. You can [tell the debugger to ignore validation exceptions](http://www.johnpapa.net/tell-the-debugger-to-ignore-silverlight-validation-exceptions/) when debugging, which lets the validation framework handle the exception without breaking execution.

Comment: Much appreciated. I think I did ask you this question in a separate thread yesterday where you had suggested a somewhat similar answer. I have also gone through a few articles that suggest the same but I wasn't sure because it looked more like a workaround rather then a solution.finally I used "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" and then implement the validation in IDataErrorInfo property. Going through the article that you have provided it looks like that is the only fix. If it is then Microsoft should provide better validation for silverlight or at least better documentation.

Comment: I personally hadn't had this problem, for some reason I must have changed some settings or something in Visual Studio, so it does seem a bit hit-and-miss. Glad you got it sorted ;)

Answer (score -3):

your setter code is throwing an exception, did your calling/client code handle/intercept the exception?

most likely not, that's why you got an "unhandle exception".

a simple test, change the throw exception to popup a message box, the unhandle exception will gone.

Comment: Thats what I thought but if you have a look at any of the silverlight validation articles or tutorials you will see that you dont need to add an exclusive event handler to handle it."ValidatesOnExceptions=True" is suppose to handle all the exceptions. But to test it I added an evenHandler BindingValidationError="ValidateTime" to catch the exception but thats not working either.